# Props always return null in Vue 3 Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

When the user clicks the Collection or Wishlist button, I expect the code to execute Axios with an ID from the  props. However, it needs to be fixed. When I press the button and check the browser console, the `gunplaId` always returns null. I've tried changing all props, but it still returns null, even in the HTTP payload. Do you know how I can fix this?

I've @foreach loop and two buttons in my blade:

```
@foreach    
<div id="app{{$loop->index}}">
        <app :gunpla-id="{{ $gunpla->id }}" :csrf-token="'{{ csrf_token() }}'">
        </app>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <collection-button :in-collection="inCollection" :gunpla-id="gunplaId" @toggle-collection="toggleCollection"></collection-button>
        <wishlist-button :in-wishlist="inWishlist" :gunpla-id="gunplaId" @toggle-wishlist="toggleWishlist"></wishlist-button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import CollectionButton from './components/CollectionButton.vue';
import WishlistButton from './components/WishlistButton.vue';

export default {
    components: {
        CollectionButton,
        WishlistButton
    },
    props: ['gunplaId', 'csrfToken'],
    setup(props) {
        const inCollection = ref(false);
        const inWishlist = ref(false);
        const toggleCollection = () => {
            console.log('gunplaId:', props.gunplaId);
            axios.post('/toggle-collection.html', { gunplaId: props.gunplaId }, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': props.csrfToken
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
        };

        const toggleWishlist = () => {
            axios.post('/toggle-wishlist.html', { gunplaId: props.gunplaId }, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': props.csrfToken
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
        };

        return {
            inCollection,
            inWishlist,
            toggleCollection,
            toggleWishlist
        };
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you receiving any values in your props?

Comment: I tried in debug but still undefined 
{gunplaId: undefined, csrfToken: undefined}

Comment: it's not solution, still get undefined